# How do I implement a dynamic process in my MUI Datagrid component within my react app (once a progress bar is complete, go to the one in next row)?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, frontend

I want to make it so that once the progress bar in the current row is complete, the progress bar in the next row will begin updating (the progress bars update based on data that is received from a server). How can I implement this feature? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Edman.jsx file code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { ProgressBar, Button } from '../components';
import { CircularProgressbar, CircularProgressbarWithChildren } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css';
import { useStateContext } from '../contexts/ContextProvider';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');


const EdmanCycle = () => {
  const { currentColor, currentMode } = useStateContext();

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(false);

  const buttonStyle = {
    padding: '10px',
    background: isButtonClicked ? "black" : currentColor,
    color: "white",
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: "10px",
    outline: 'none',
    boxShadow: isButtonClicked ? 'none' : '2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    transition: 'background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s',
  };

  const initialRows = [
    { id: 1, step: "M1-11 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: (Math.round((data["totalStepTime"] - data["currentStepTime"]) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) },
    { id: 2, step: "MeOH Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 3, step: "M1-12 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 4, step: "Alkaline Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 5, step: "M1-23 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 6, step: "PITC Solution", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 7, step: "M1-32 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 8, step: "Alkaline Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 9, step: "M1-21 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 10, step: "MeOH Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 11, step: "M2-14 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 12, step: "Waste B Purge", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 13, step: "M1-16 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 14, step: "DDH2O Wash (Raman Spec #1)", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 15, step: "MM1-68 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 16, step: "M2-18 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 17, step: "PAUSE", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 18, step: "M1-61 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 19, step: "MeOH Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 20, step: "M1-14 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 21, step: "EA Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 22, step: "M2-14 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 23, step: "Waste B Purge", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 24, step: "M2-41 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 25, step: "EA Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 26, step: "M1-45 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 27, step: "TFA Bath", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 28, step: "M1-54 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 29, step: "EA Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 30, step: "M2-15 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 31, step: "Waste A Purge", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 32, step: "M2-52 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 33, step: "EA (secondary) Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 80, time: null },
    { id: 34, step: "M2-25 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 35, step: "Waste A Purge", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 36, step: "M1-41 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 37, step: "M2-51 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 38, step: "MeOH Wash", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 39, step: "M1-16 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 40, step: "DDH2O Wash (Raman Spec #2)", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 41, step: "M1-61 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 42, step: "MM1-18 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
    { id: 43, step: "M2-18 Switch", status: "Incomplete", progress: 0, time: null },
  ];

  const [activeRowIndex, setActiveRowIndex] = useState(null);
  const [progressBars, setProgressBars] = useState(initialRows)

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('receiveEdman', (data) => {
      setData(data);
      if (activeRowIndex !== null && progressBars[activeRowIndex]?.progress !== 100) {
        handleProgressBarUpdate(activeRowIndex);
      }
      //handleProgressBarUpdate(activeRowIndex);
    });
  }, [socket, activeRowIndex, progressBars]);

  const handleProgressBarUpdate = (index) => {
    const updatedProgressBars = [...progressBars];
    updatedProgressBars[index].progress += Math.round(data["currentStepTime"] * 100 / data["totalStepTime"]);

    if (updatedProgressBars[index].progress >= 100) {
      // Reset the progress of the current row to 100
      updatedProgressBars[index].progress = 100;

      // Move to the next row by incrementing the index
      const nextIndex = index + 1;
      if (nextIndex < updatedProgressBars.length) {
        setActiveRowIndex(nextIndex);
      } else {
        setActiveRowIndex(null); // No more rows to update
      }
    }

    setProgressBars(updatedProgressBars);
  };

  const startButtonClicked = () => {
    setIsButtonClicked(true);
    // Simulate a delay to reset the button's state after a certain period
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsButtonClicked(false);
    }, 300);
  
    const cycleData = text;
    socket.emit('startButtonClicked', cycleData); // Emit the data to the server with the 'buttonClick' event
  
    // Set the activeRowIndex to the index of the first row (0)
    setActiveRowIndex(0);
    handleProgressBarUpdate(0);
  };

  const ProgressBarCell = ({ value }) => {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        {/* onProgressChange={updateRowProgress} */}
        <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={value}/>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'Step Number', width: 140 },
    { field: 'step', headerName: 'Edman Cycle Step', width: 170 },
    {
      field: 'progress',
      headerName: 'Step Progress',
      width: 170,
      editable: true,
      // isActive={params.rowIndex === activeRowIndex}
      renderCell: (params) => <ProgressBarCell value={params.value}/>,
      progressChangeCallback: handleProgressBarUpdate,
    },
    {
      field: 'status',
      headerName: 'Status',
      width: 170,
      editable: true,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        const progress = params.row.progress;
        if (progress === 0) {
          return 'Incomplete';
        } else if (progress >= 100) {
          return 'Complete';
        } else {
          return 'In Progress';
        }
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'time',
      headerName: 'Time Remaining (minutes)',
      type: 'number',
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'flow_vol',
      headerName: 'Flow Volume',
      type: 'number',
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'flow_rate',
      headerName: 'Flow Rate',
      type: 'number',
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'fluid',
      headerName: 'Fluid Type',
      type: 'number',
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="mt-24">
      <div className="flex gap-10 flex-row justify-center">
        <div className="bg-white dark:text-gray-200 dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg m-3 p-4 rounded-2xl md:w-850" > 
          <h3 className="heading text-3xl font-semibold items-center flex items-center">Total Number of Cycles: {data["totalCycles"]} 
          <div className='ml-13 p-6'>
            <div className='border border-gray-400 rounded px-2 py-1'>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder='# of cycles'
                value={text}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div> 
          </div> 
          <button style={buttonStyle} className={isButtonClicked ? "black" : {currentColor}} onClick={startButtonClicked} type="button">
            START
          </button>
          </h3> 
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
            <h3 className="heading text-3xl font-semibold items-center justify-center">Progress:</h3>
              <ProgressBar bgcolor="#99ff66" progress={Math.round(data["currentTime"] * 100 / data["totalTime"])}  height={30} />
          </div>
          <h4 className="heading text-2xl font-semibold items-center justify-center">Current Cycle Number: {data["currentCycle"]}</h4>
          <h4 className="heading text-2xl font-semibold items-center justify-center mt-5">Time Remaining in Current Cycle: {(data["totalTime"] - data["currentTime"]).toFixed(2)} minutes</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div
            className="rounded-2xl md:w-700 p-4 m-3"
            style={{ backgroundColor: currentColor }}
          >
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center ">
              <p className="font-semibold text-white text-3xl">Cycle Step: {data["currentStep"]}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4 items-center justify-center mr-20">
              <ProgressBar bgcolor="#99ccff" progress={Math.round(data["currentStepTime"] * 100 / data["totalStepTime"])}  height={30} />
              <h6 className="heading text-xl font-semibold items-center justify-center mt-5 text-white">Time Remaining in Current Step: {(Math.round((data["totalStepTime"] - data["currentStepTime"]) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)} minutes</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-10 flex-row justify-center mt-5 items-center ml-9">
        <div className="w-800 flex bg-white dark:text-gray-200 dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg rounded-2xl p-6 m-3 justify-center items-center text-white" style={{ backgroundColor: currentColor }}>
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <p className="text-3xl font-semibold mr-9">Cycle Tracker:</p>
          </div>
          <div className='mt-10' style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}>
            <CircularProgressbarWithChildren
              value={Math.round(data["currentTime"] * 100 / data["totalTime"])} 
              text={`Edman Cycle: ${Math.round(data["currentTime"] * 100 / data["totalTime"])}%`}
              background
              styles={{
                // Customize the root svg element
                root: {},
                // Customize the path, i.e. the "completed progress"
                path: {
                  stroke: '#99ff66',
                  // Whether to use rounded or flat corners on the ends - can use 'butt' or 'round'
                  strokeLinecap: 'butt',
                  // Customize transition animation
                  transition: 'stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s',
                  transformOrigin: 'center center',
                },
                // Customize the circle behind the path, i.e. the "total progress"
                trail: {
                  // Trail color
                  stroke: 'white',
                  // Whether to use rounded or flat corners on the ends - can use 'butt' or 'round'
                  strokeLinecap: 'butt',
                  // Rotate the trail
                  transform: 'rotate(0.25turn)',
                  transformOrigin: 'center center',
                },
                // Customize the text
                text: {
                  // Text color
                  fill: 'white',
                  // Text size
                  fontSize: '7px',
                },
                // Customize background - only used when the `background` prop is true
                background: {
                  fill: 'black',
                },
              }} >
              <div className="container" style={{ width: "84%" }}>
                <CircularProgressbar
                  value={Math.round(data["currentStepTime"] * 100 / data["totalStepTime"])}
                  text={`Current Step: ${data["currentStep"]}`}
                  styles={{
                    path: {
                      stroke: "#99ccff",
                      strokeLinecap: 'butt',
                    },
                    trail: {
                      stroke: `#a9a9a9`,
                      strokeLinecap: 'butt',
                    },
                    text: {
                      // Text color
                      fill: 'white',
                      // Text size
                      fontSize: '5px',
                      transform: 'translateY(10px)'
                    },
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div className='mr-9' style={{ height: 600, width: '70%' }}>
            {/* <DataGridProgress /> */}
            <DataGrid
              rows={progressBars}
              columns={columns}
              // onEditCellChangeCommitted={(params) =>
              //   handleProgressChange(params.id, params.value)
              // }
            />
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EdmanCycle;
```

As of now, the progress bar is not updating once the first one is complete.

Comment: You can try fetching with an async function with chunks of data